# Removing unecessary permissions from AndroidManifest that Unity+Plugins put in there?

Tags: unity, android, permission

My game has a lot of unnecessary permissions added to it, I suspect some are coming from plugins and some from Unity. I've looked at all the AndroidManifest.xml files and couldn't find any that use those permissions so I suspect it's added as a post build process or some other way by the plugins wrapped up in a binary or something.

Is there a way to remove those permissions in a post process build step?

Answer (score 1):

You have to build from Unity into an Gradle Android project ("Export Project") and then edit/replace the file before building the APK using Android Studio.

More info on Unity's website: https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/android-BuildProcess.html

Comment: ah that's a huge pain especially for cloud builds...